# success method wont call - nodejs using express

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

so i have this method in my nodeJs server code which need to insert something to the mongoDB, problem is that even what it did insert (i see in the DB after it) it wont get to the sucess call.

all i want is to make an alert in my client saying "done"

i am using nodejs via express.

this is my server side :

```
exports.savePre = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {

        // Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
        var json = req.body.jsonToSave;
        var date = req.body.date;
        var name = req.body.name;
        var ArrayOfSlice = req.body.ArrayOfSlice;


        // Set our collection
        var collection = db.get('PresentationCollection');

        // Submit to the DB
        collection.insert({
            "JsonToSave": json,
            "Date": date,
            "Name": name,
            "ArrayOfPoints": ArrayOfSlice
        }, function (err, inserted)
        {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
            res.end();

            if (err)
            {
                // If it failed, return error
                res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
            }
            else
            {
                res.send("bla");

                //res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
                //res.end();
                //res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                // If it worked, set the header so the address bar doesn't still say /test
                //res.end();
                // // And forward to success page
                // res.redirect("userlist");
             }
        });

    }
}
```

this is my call in my client :

```
  function savePre()
        {
            var exporter = new THREE.SceneExporter();
            var sceneJInson = JSON.stringify(exporter.parse(scene));

            var CameraPosition = camera.position;
            //var CameraLookAt = lookAtPosition;

            // Array Of Slice, each row is a slice - here we will add all the slices :)
            var arrayOfSlice = [{ cameraPosition: CameraPosition }];
            //                    { cameraPosition: CameraPosition, CameraLookAt: CameraLookAt },
            //                    { cameraPosition: CameraPosition, CameraLookAt: CameraLookAt }];

            // TODO : give the name where the user chose, this is only test, date is also a test
            var parameters = { name: "eranNew", date: new Date(), jsonToSave: sceneJInson, ArrayOfSlice: JSON.stringify(arrayOfSlice) };

            $.ajax({
                url: '/savePre',
                type: 'POST',
                data: parameters,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("done");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("error");
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        }
```

any help will be grate.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you write several times headers.

```
  collection.insert({
        "JsonToSave": json,
        "Date": date,
        "Name": name,
        "ArrayOfPoints": ArrayOfSlice
    }, function (err, inserted)
    {

        if (err)
        {
            res.send(500, "There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        }
        else
        {
            res.send(200, "bla");

         }
    });
```

Comment: still not work, it did get to the else and create message 200 with "bla" but in the client it reach only error part and not success success (i see it in my debug)

Comment: @eran10 If you try w/o jQuery (xhr) ?

Comment: Could you try using just XMLHttpRequest without jQuery?

Comment: how do i write it down ? can you give me a simple example?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/XMLHttpRequest use also https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/XMLHttpRequest/FormData

Answer (score 0):

i was able to solve it by using this :

```
 if (err)
            {
                res.send(500, "There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
            }
            else
            {
                res.statusCode = 200;

                res.json("OK");
            }
```